# error: while running "npm create feathers@latest feathers-chat"?

Tags: node.js, windows, rest, npm, feathersjs

I am trying to follow the *getting-started* guide on feathers website. I am running the command:
`npm create feathers@latest feathers-chat`
on Powershell (on Windows).
I am getting the error following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\[...]\node_modules\@feathersjs\generators\package.json
```

It seems like the problem is with the double "C:\C:\Users..." in the path.
I don't know where it comes from.
When I am trying to create a react app `npm init react-app` it works successfully.

Any suggestion how to solve/probe this would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: As of 5.0.20 this should be working now. It's been honestly surprising how difficult it still is to migrate an existing NodeJS package to ES modules.